# change levels of values in geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to change the levels of the values see below, this should change the order in the legend. I want to define it in ggplot

```
ggplot(data=outdf4,aes(x=log2_ratio, y =log10Pvalue))+
geom_point(aes(colour = lab), size = 4) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("Not Regulated"= "red","Regulated"= "green"))
```

I guess this should be the way to do
`levels=c("Regulated","Not Regulated"))`
I tried in both `geom_point` and `scale_colour_manual` but it does not work.

Comment: If you don't want to reverse the order of the factor variable itself then you could do: `+ guides(colour=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))`

Comment: I tried to reverse but I think I make a mistake where I insert `levels=c("Regulated","Not Regulated"))`.

Comment: You don't need to use `levels` anywhere if you change the order in `guides`.

Comment: Another option (instead of using `guides`) would be to load the `forcats` package and then do `colour=fct_rev(lab)` instead of `colour=lab`.

Comment: With `forcats ` can I also define the pattern manually?

Comment: Yes. Use `fct_relevel`. See the help (`?fct_relevel`) for details.

Comment: Is there a way to order manually the values inside `guide_legend`? Something like `guides(colour=guide_legend(levels=c("Regulated","Not Regulated")))`